# phpunit and CodeCoverage

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I'm running a vagrant box w/ a simple lamp stack. I've installed phpunit globally via composer :

```
composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.1.*"
```

When I run phpunit I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 46

HP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php' (include_path='/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/php-timer:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 46
```

My research seems to imply that it's a problem with CodeCoverage not installing, but I'm having problems trying to get that installed. I've tried to install via composer and can't get it working.

Via Composer, I've tried adding to the global:

```
composer global require "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "3.0.*@dev"
```

and I get this output:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package phpunit/php-code-coverage could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.1.3 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ~2.0 -> no matching package found.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.1.3 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ~2.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit == 4.1.3.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.1.3].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

No clue what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to reinstall code-coverage 2.0 first

> composer global require "phpunit/php-code-coverage":"2.0.*@dev"

then you install phpunit

> composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.1.*"